# undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to Rails and am working through the [Ruby on Rails getting started tutorial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html). I'm getting an error on 5.7 Showing Posts that says `'undefined method title' for nil:NilClass'`. Any assistance you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
def new
end

def create
    @post = Post.new(params[:post].permit(:title, :text))

    @post.save
    redirect_to @post
end

private
def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :text)
end

def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

end



<p>
  <strong>Title:</strong>
  <%= @post.title %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Text:</strong>
  <%= @post.text %>
</p>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `show` method is private, you need to move it above the keyword.

In the future you may prefer to write

```
def some_method
  ...
end
private :some_method
```

to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, this worked for me.
Moved the "show" definition to above the private block. I think that the order of the Getting Started doc may have been confusing.

Comment: Googling and using stack overflow are a hidden feature of the tutorial :p